# Why (and where) is CORS blocking an NGINX proxy request to a Node instance?

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, cors

I'm in the process of moving some NodeJS / Vue sites over to a new server that is using PM2 for managing the processes.  Since there are multiple domains at play using different listening ports, I've started setting up NGINX to proxy traffic to the respective Node processes.

I was able to get the main pages to load.  One domain I tested began showing CORS errors in the browser's developer console when trying to communicate with another server in the environment.  I was able to correct that by adding the necessary Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers settings to the destination server.

Now, the developer console is showing the error below and I can't figure out how / where to address it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8083/sockjs-node/info?t=1702065977206. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

I've tried a number of different configuration changes from researching the errors but haven't seen any change in the errors given by the developer tools.